# Let m be a positive integer and a, b, c, and d be integers. If a = c (mod m) and b = d (mod m), then prove a∙b = c∙d (mod m).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

To prove this I believe I just need to show that (cd-an)/m is an integer.

Just FYI the definition I got from the book of a = c (mod m) is: m divides c - a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \equiv c \bmod m$ then $a-c = km$ for some integer $k$. That is, $a = c + km$. Likewise, if $b \equiv d \bmod m$ then $b = d + jm$ for some integer $j$.

Multiply these together:

$$ab = (c+km)(d + jm).$$

Try to show the right-hand side has the form $cd + (\text{some integer})m$.

Comment: That was perfect thanks for the help